# Faster algorithm for counting active calls

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

We are implementing a density report for a call center. The result must be displayed as table with a row per day showing the maximum number of **simultaneously** active calls during that day.

We are building the lib behind the UI. The contract specifies we receive the number of calls for that day and two arrays of integers, one with the start time and one with the end time of each call, so, for example:

For a given day just two calls are received: One goes from time 20 to 30 and the other one from 10 to 20. The maximum number simultaneously calls is 1.

On the other hand, for another day, also two calls are received, one from 10 to 45 and the other from 15 to 40 then the maximum number of simultaneously calls is 2.

The contract for the web service is this

```
public static int GetMaxDensity(int N, int[] X, int[] Y)
```

And the data looks like this (suppose 3 calls where received that day). First one from 10 to 25, second one from 12 to 30 and third one from 20 to 23.

```
N = 3, 
X = {10, 12, 20}
Y = {25, 30, 23}
```

And the return must be: 3.

I've implemented this solution:

```
public static int GetMaxDensity(int N, int[] X, int[] Y) 
{
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
  {
      int count = 0, t = X[i];
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
      {
        if (X[j] <= t && t < Y[j])
        count++;
      }
      result = Math.max(count, result);
   }
   return result;
}
```

And it works great when the number of calls is up to 1000 (weekends) but within work days the number is pretty big and the calculation takes so long (>5 minutes). I now the reason could be my solution is using two nested cycles but I don't have pretty much experience with complex algorithms so my question is:

Given that I just need the maximum number of simultaneously calls (not the times nor the callers), which could be a faster way to perform this calculation if there is one.

Comment: if one call is from 10 to 40 and second call is from 20 to 45, what should be the density ? I think 2, is it ?

Comment: @mprabhat Yes. Cause from 20 to 40 two calls were active.

Comment: I just copied your code and ran five tests of two 50,000 arrays. Each of the arrays are randomly generated values where x is less than 100, and y is less than the corresponding x+ 100. they came back in 24, 12, 12, 24, 18 seconds.  This was on my laptop. Did you perhaps clean up the code so you could post it here? If so, maybe the loops aren't the problem. What has your profiler revealed?

Comment: @dbrown0708 - that's an interesting observation. I only have c# handy, but see similar numbers to yours (29,000 milliseconds for N=50,000).

Comment: @dbrown0708 The contractual worse time (quality of service requirement) must be no greater than 10 seconds per 100.000 calls analysis.

Comment: How does the goal you're trying to reach impact the difference in performance? 30 seconds for N=50,000 is a long way from 5 minutes for N>1,000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As N grows your time grows rapidly (N*N). A simple solution (if your times are in intervals of minutes past midnight) would be to create an array of 1440 ints that will contain the change in call counts for each minute through the day. Then you can loop just once from 0 to N-1, and for each element, adjust the count of the call count delta at that point in time by incrementing the value at the time the call starts, and decrementing at the time it ends.  After that, just look through the counts to obtain the largest value. This should be much faster for larger values of N.

Since 1440 is a constant (for the last step), and the inputs do not need to be sorted, this should have linear time complexity. This algorithm's run time is not affected by the average call length.

```
public static int GetMaxDensity(int N, int[] X, int[] Y) {
    int rangeStart = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int rangeEnd = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if (X[i] < rangeStart) rangeStart = X[i];
        if (Y[i] > rangeEnd) rangeEnd = Y[i];
    } 
    int rangeSize = rangeEnd - rangeStart + 1;
    int[] histogram = new int[rangeSize];
    for (int t = 0; t < rangeSize; t++) histogram[t] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        histogram[X[i]-rangeStart]++;
        histogram[Y[i]-rangeStart]--;
    }
    int maxCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int t = 0; t < rangeSize; t++) {
        count += histogram[t];
        if (count > maxCount) maxCount = count;
    }
    return maxCount;        
}
```

For comparision, with N=50,000 and random call lengths between 1 and 40 minutes, the algorithm in the question used 29,043 milliseconds, and this algorithm used 8 milliseconds. I ran these tests in c#, but they should be comparable to what Java would produce.

Comment: n*n =n^2, it is polynomial time, and it does not grow exponentially.

Comment: @hatchet The thing is I can't close the gap that way for one day. For my question I put that as an example but actually the report must be dynamically generable say from within 13:00 of tuesday to 16:00 of friday and between that times the numbers of start call and end call are not bounded by any specific integer (as, in this case, the number of minutes in the day).

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul - What is the unit of time measure? If the times are given as integer values, and you have a range of time over which you need to compute the max calls, then this solution should be able to be used. The size of the histogram will just be the number of time intervals between the start and end of the range rather than fixed at 1440. If you still think that's not the case, possibly a more realistic example in the question would be helpful.

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul - I've edited my answer to account for a somewhat arbitrary range of times present in the input to show what I meant about it still being applicable. The only caveat is that the range present in the inputs should not be huge. If you could have huge ranges of time (many millions of units), then the approach of other answers here where you sort the starts and ends, and then walk through the two kind of in parallel (advancing in the array with the lower time), and keeping count as you go is the way to go.

Comment: @hatchet Actually that couldn't be possible (given that the Web Service expect an array of integers). I just implemented your solution and its amazingly faster! Mine one took 47750.562ms for 100.000 calls. Your one just 10.245ms.

Now the thing is how many space will this consume but that doesn't matter right now.

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul - the space is approximately (1 + theOldestEndTime - theEarliestStartTime) from your inputs, multiplied by 4 (the size of an int). So if the earliest start was 600, and the oldest end time was 4000, it would need 13,604 bytes.

Comment: int[] X ={11,12,15,17,18,13}; 
int[] Y ={16,34,24,19,19,18};
int N = 6;
With this algo the result is 4. Is this correct? @ 18 there are 5 active calls

Comment: @ejb_guy - from the OP's question ("One goes from time 20 to 30 and the other one from 10 to 20. The maximum number simultaneously calls is 1.") it seemed that call times were inclusive of start time, but exclusive of end time. So at t=18 the calls are 12-34, 15-24, 17-19, 18-19. 13-18 has ended at t=18. If inclusive of both start and end are desired, then in my code above, the line for modifying the end delta would be histogram[1+Y[i]-rangeStart]--;

Comment: Getting ArrayOutOfBound with this change. Some more tweaking is required. int rangeSize = rangeEnd - rangeStart + 1+1; Why extra +1 not sure

Comment: @ejb_guy - right, sorry...would also need to increase the size to int rangeSize = rangeEnd - rangeStart + 2. The extra +1 needed because if range 13-18 includes 18, then the count would go up at t=13 and down at t=19.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to propose a different algorithm. Given that there are maximum 24*60 = 1440 minutes day, why not make a histogram array to calculate the number of simultaneous calls for each minute.

```
public static int GetMaxDensity(int N, int[] X, int[] Y) 
{
  int[] h = new int[1440];
  // loop through all calls
  for (int i=0; i<N ; i++){
    addIt(X[i], Y[i], h);
  }

  // find max
  int m = 0;
  for(int i =0 ; i<1440; i++){
    if (h[i]>m)
      m = h[i];
  }
  return m;
}

// counting for one call
public static void addIt(int x, int y, int[] h){
  for ( int i=x;i<y;i++){
    h[i]++;
  }
}
```

The complexity is O(m*n), where m being the average length of a call. Since the number of calls could be much more than 1000, so with some luck this algorithm would be faster in practice.

Comment: Why minutes? Will not this make the values on timeline discreet. Should not seconds need to be considered.

Comment: @ejb_guy In that case: 24*3600 = 86400 minutes. If the number of calls is very very large, it will still be a good solution.:)

Comment: If there are few calls with long durations? I am not sure if this is right solution. I feel this algo is hiding the performance bottleneck in addIt method by being small and simple

Comment: @ejb_guy Of course the performance will be bad in that case. For algorithms it's all about the size of the problem isn't it? I believe under some circumstances even the O(n^2) algorithm in the original post will have the best performance.

Comment: Somehow I feel that matrix manipulation has some role to play in efficient algo for this. Let me bang my head.

Comment: @ejb_guy - this approach can be optimized to remove the effect of call length from the running time. You can see what I mean in my similar (and earlier) answer in which I've made that change.

Comment: @XiZhang As previously commented, I can't close the gap that way for one day. For my question I put that as an example but actually the report must be dynamically generable say from within 13:00 of tuesday to 16:00 of friday and between that times the numbers of start call and end call are not bounded by any specific integer (as, in this case, the number of minutes in the day).

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is very slow because it literally tests all possible cases, which is O(n^2).

Assuming that your calls are ordered when you receive them, here is an O(n) algorithm:
[EDIT: second array should be sorted]

```
    int max;
    int i=0,j=0,count=0;
    while(i<n && j<n){
        if(x[i]<y[j]){ //new call received
            count++;
            max = count>max? count:max;
            i++;
        }else if(x[i]==x[j]){ //receive new call at the same time of end call
            i++;
            j++;
        }else { //call ended
            count--;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return max;
  }
```

[**note**: this code will most likely throw array index out of range error, but should be good enough to demonstrate the idea so you can implement the rest]

if the calls are not sorted, the algorithm is O(n lg n):

```
array_of_calldata a = x union y
a.sort();
foreach(calldata d in a){
    if (d is new call) count++;
    else count--;
}
return max_value_of_count;
```

Comment: I don't think the first approach would work. Think about the case as {{12,25}{20,21}{22,23}} With your algorithm the result would still be 3 while it should be 2.

Comment: @kayson Thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate on the case the calls are not sorted given that my problem is precisely that.

Answer (score 1):

Sort all calls by the start time. Iterate through the list and keep an "active calls" list, sorted by end time. Should look similar to this:

```
public class DensityReport {

  static int count;

  static class Call {
    public Call(int x, int y) {
      double f = 0.1/(++count);
      start = x + f;
      end = y + f;
    }
    double start;
    double end;
  }

  public static int getMaxDensity(int n, int[] x, int[] y) {
    // Calls sorted by start time
    TreeSet<Call> calls = new TreeSet<Call>(new Comparator<Call>() {
      public int compare(Call c1, Call c2) {
        return c1.start < c2.start ? -1 : c1.start > c2.start ? 1 : 0;
      }
    });

    // Add all calls to the sorted set.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      calls.add(new Call(x[i], y[i]));
    }

    int max = 0;
    // Active calls sorted by end time
    TreeSet<Call> activeCalls = new TreeSet<Call>(new Comparator<Call>() {
      public int compare(Call c1, Call c2) {
        return c1.end < c2.end ? -1 : c1.end > c2.end ? 1 : 0;
      }
    });

    for (Call call: calls) {
      // Remove all calls that end before the current call starts.
      while(activeCalls.size() > 0 && activeCalls.first().end < call.start) {
        activeCalls.pollFirst();
      }
      activeCalls.add(call);
      if (activeCalls.size() > max) {
        max = activeCalls.size();
      }
    }
    return max;
  }
}
```

Runtime should be O(n log n)

P.S.: It should be possible to simplify this if we can assume that the calls are ordered by the start time already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For just 1 call it seems to work but from then it get stuck within the: while loop `while(activeCalls.size() > 0 && activeCalls.first().end < call.start) {
         activeCalls.remove(activeCalls.first());
       }`

Comment: Ooops, sorry, fixed the comparators and replaced remove() with pollFirst() in the loop. The problem was that I thought I could ignore the equals case in the coparators, but that didn't work for remove() (and wasn't really clean anyway)

Comment: p.s. also had to change the Call class to simplify the comparison

Comment: Thanks for your reply. +1 'cause I implemented your solution and alt ought not as fast as hatchet one It is by far fastest than mine one. Just one question, I don't have pretty much experience with the collections you're using but I guess your solution is better with space complexity than hatchet one (I'm I wrong?).

Comment: The space consumption for hatchet's solution is linear to the distance between the start of the first call and the end of the last call. The memory complexity for my solution is linear to the input size. So it depends. The run time for his solution is O(n * m), where m is the length of the longest call. What I don't like about this is that you need to make additional assumptions, decreasing robustness: Calls are assumed to be short, the total time is assumed to be limited. So if somebody starts to measure the call lengths in milliseconds, or if the time span increases, there is an issue.

Comment: p.s. To see the issue just try some extreme call times, e.g. [0, Integer.MAX_VALUE]. If you are perfectly sure this will never happen, there is obviously no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use two lists, add the X[i] Y[i] pairs to those lists.  The first list sorted on call start time, the second sorted on endtime.  Iterate over the lists only stepping the lowest time list.

```
class Call {
    int start;
    int end;
}

Call callsSortedOnStart[];
Call callsSortedOnEnd[];

int indexStart = 0;  // Position in the array
int indexEnd = 0;

int nCalls = 0;      // Current density of calls
int maxCalls = 0;    // Maximum density of calls

while(indexStart < callsSortedOnStart.length && indexEnd < callsSortedOnEnd.length) {
    while(callsSortedOnStart[indexStart].start <= callsSortedOnEnd[indexEnd].end) {
        indexStart++;
        nCalls++;
    }
    maxCalls = max(maxCalls, nCalls);

    while(callsSortedOnStart[indexStart].start > callsSortedOnEnd[indexEnd].end) {
        indexEnd++;
        nCalls--;
    }
}
```

Comment: If he sorts the two array he will loose the start and end time of every call, he needs max count of call made between any period.

Comment: @mprabhat Therefore store start--end pairs in a list; added some code to clarify this point

Comment: @KaspervandenBerg thanks for your reply. But I guess my english is not so good, I understand what you mean with using two list but don't understand when you say "stepping the lowest time list". Do you mean iterate over the list with the minimum first item cause to create the list will take O(N) and to take the minimum of all the list O(N^2) AFAIK. And nop. Isn't homework is jobwork. Kinda weird, actually I'm not a computer scientist. I'm a lawyer :)

Comment: I'll show what I mean, but Hatchet's approach is faster.  Sorry for the 'homework' assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Make array of call events. Call event is just a structure with time field and startend field with value +1 or -1 for start of call and end of call. Sort this array by time field (if times are equal, then use the second field, end event before start event). Initialize CurrentCalls = 0. Iterate array, add StartEnd field to CurrentCalls. Max value of CurrentCalls during array scanning is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your durations by start time. That way, when a start time in your inner loop falls outside of the range provided by your outer loop, you can `break` the inner loop.

Comment: One question, is it possible, then, that if all the calls fall inside the range (maybe for some weir behavior) then the running time will be O(n^2) I'm right?

Comment: You also might luck out and none of the call overlap, too. You don't indicate any patterns in your dataset which might lead to that kind of assumption. Also, this method requires no additional memory to be allocated compared to your original solution.